# Django linking allauth to google-api sign in

Tags: django, google-api, google-calendar-api

So I got the google button to link to http://localhost:8000/accounts/google/login/ and it displays the below

> Sign In Via Google You are about to sign in using a third party
> account from Google.
>
> Continue

and if I click the continue button I get the following. How would I continue from here to authenticate a user using the google-api with allauth. I have the OAuth consent form with a OAuth 2.0 client id for a web app.

> Authorization Error Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
>
> You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's
> OAuth 2.0 policy.

OAuth2.0 Client

```
Authorized JavaScript origins
For use with requests from a browser
URIs *      
http://127.0.0.1:8000
http://localhost:8000
https://url.com

Authorized redirect URIs
For use with requests from a web server
URIs *      
http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/google/login/callback
http://localhost:8000/accounts/google/login/callback
https://url.com/accounts/google/login/callback
```

login.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
 
  <button><a href="{% url 'signup' %}">Sign up</a></button>
  <a id="google_login" href="/accounts/google/login" class="btn btn-success">
    Sign in with Google
  </a>
  
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Does the error popup provide any other information? Is there any mention of URIs not being correct?

Comment: Looks to me like you have to review the settings of your app in the google dev console

Comment: If you’re the app developer, make sure that these request details comply with Google policies.
redirect_uri: http://localhost:8000/accounts/google/login/callback/

Comment: It seems switching it to URIs *      
http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/google/login/callback / worked.